# PHP check if nested value in array exists

Tags: php, arrays, loops, nested

I have the following array $students:

```
[
(int) 0 => [
    'Students' => [
        'number' => '1364249',
        'first_name' => 'a',
        'last_name' => 'asda',
        'email' => 'MajC5@corporation.uk'
    ],
    'Responses' => [
        'id' => '2'
    ]
  ]
]
```

There could me multiple students here. I have a variable before I get this array, which is a student number. I must then check this array to see if the student number exists anywhere. How would I do this? I tried the below but get an error 'Undefined index: number '.

```
$student_id = $this->Auth->user('Student.number');

    $authorised = false;
    foreach ($students as $student) {
        if (isset($student['Students'])) {
            if ($student['number'] == $student_id) {
                $authorised = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm not good at PHP so I apologise if this is really obvious, I suspect I'm just doing the loop through the array very wrong, would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Can you post the actual array without pre tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($array as $student) {
     if (isset($student['Students'])) {
         if ($student['Students']['number'] == $student_id) {
              $authorised = true;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: $student['Students']['number'] is what I had trouble working out.. thanks!